# TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments in django

Tags: python, django

I am passing username and password from a template to my views.py and trying to save it in my database but it is giving error - this constructor takes no arguments

my views.py -

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = request.POST
        if 'submit' in post:
            u = user(username = post['username'], password = post['password'])
            u.save()
    return render(request, 'XO/home_page.html')
```

my models.py -

```
class user:
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

my template -

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="form" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            Username: <input type="text" name="username"/>
            Password: <input type="text" name="password"/>
            <button type="submit" name="submit">
                Submit
            </button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any idea why I am getting this error..??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I hope this is example code: you should never store passwords as plain text. Django already has a User model that you should use.

Comment: Yep it is an example code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should inherit the model from the `models.Model` class:

```
class user(models.Model):
    ...
```

Also note that you have an indentation problem: `__str__()` method should be one level right, inside the `user` class.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Don't know how I missed that thing.